# Can we use `const` instead of `let` everywhere?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, immutability, flowtype

With `flowtype` we prefer `const` against `let`

I have function that needs to be worked in most performant way and it's works well for me, it's compare two arrays, so it's cool example for my question:

```
/**
* @function compare
* @description function compares two arrays with ids to figure out: are they equal? (elements position can be different)
* @param arraFrom {Array}
* @param arraTo {Array}
* @param compareFunction {Function}
* @returns {Boolean}
*/
function compare(arraFrom, arraTo, compareFunction) {
  let notEqual = true;
  if(arraFrom.length !== arraTo.length) return false;
    for (let i = 0; i < arraFrom.length; i++) {
      notEqual = true;
      for (let j = 0; j < arraTo.length; j++) {
        if (compareFunction ?
            compareFunction(arraFrom[i], arraTo[j]) :
          arraFrom[i] === arraTo[j]) {
          notEqual = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (notEqual) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Question is: how can we implement it without using `let` in the most performant way?

Thank you!

Comment: Stop and think a little while about what `const` actually means. It's an abbreviation of *constant*. How will having a *constant* variable (however oxymoronic that might sound) in your code work when you would like to change its value?

Comment: This question feels like a "please rewrite my code" request hidden beneath the guise of an interesting question.

Comment: none of your `let`'s can be replaced with `const` as they all change. `const` is for constant variables and is read-only

Comment: If performance is important here, one easy performance tune is to get rid of `compareFunction ?` inside the loop and do it once at start of function.. eg. `compareFunction = compareFunction ? compareFunction : function (a,b) { return a === b };`

Comment: I don't think that function actually does what you want in case you have duplicates in the `arraFrom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of iterating the arrays by mutating index variables, you can use `for…of` loops:

```
function compare(arraFrom, arraTo, compareFunction) {
  let notEqual = true;
  if(arraFrom.length !== arraTo.length) return false;
  for (const a of arraFrom) {
    notEqual = true;
    for (const b of arraTo) {
      if (compareFunction ? compareFunction(a,b) : a === b) {
        notEqual = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (notEqual) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Instead of that mutable `notEqual` flag, you can simply return early:

```
function compare(arraFrom, arraTo, compareFunction) {
  if (arraFrom.length !== arraTo.length) return false;
  outer: for (const a of arraFrom) {
    for (const b of arraTo) {
      if (compareFunction ? compareFunction(a,b) : a === b) {
        continue outer;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But that's pretty unreadable. I'd recommend to use the following:

```
function compare(arrayFrom, arrayTo, compareFunction) {
  if (arrayFrom.length !== arrayTo.length) return false;
  const test = typeof compareFunction == "function"
    ? a => b => compareFunction(a, b)
    : a => b => a === b;
  return arrayFrom.every(a => arrayTo.some(test(a)));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this messing with how `const` is supposed to act? As in, being a constant? Also, careful with `for...of`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen As the value of a and b never get mutated, I see nothing wrong in using `const`.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen I don't see what I'm messing with? All of those variables are constant, they never change. They're just recreated in a new scope. And since the OP asked about ES6 solutions, I expect him to know about compatibility :-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox You might need to get accustomed to functional programming a bit, but the code is much more understandable. With boolean flags or labelled jumps it's really hard to figure out what a function does. In contrast, the last line of the last snippet literally says that the functions tests whether for `every` item from `arrayFrom` there is `some` item from `arrayTo` to which it compares equal.

Comment: I think that `compareFunction` shouldn't accept two types - rather split up `compare` into two separate functions `compare`/`equals`.

Comment: @ftor What do you mean by "two types"? It just uses `===` as the default if no function is passed.

Comment: `undefined` is a type too.

Comment: @ftor You mean `compare` should not be overloaded? Yeah, why not, but I wanted to keep the interface with the optional parameter from the original code. Your first comment sounded like you were concerned about the signature of `compareFunction` (when it is a function)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change it's value so you can use it everywhere. The difference is that you can't change the value of `const`.There are no other differences except that one

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you prefer `const` over `let`?
`const` hast the property that it won't let itself change. You won't get and error when trying to change it though. Instead it will just keep its initial value.
The code you posted has absolutely no place for `const`.

Comment: Depends on where you execute it. Node doesn't seem to mind. Sorry though, if browsers do. Will note that.